# Change href to anchor on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

This is probably an easy question but I couldn't figure it out: I am trying to change a href to a variable using JavaScript/jQuery. I am using the [Bootstrap Collapse Plugin](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp). My code looks basically like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Collapsible Panel</h2>
  <p>Click on the collapsible panel to open and close it.</p>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

however panels are created dynamically and at some point, I have to change the ids and hrefs. E.g.:

```
<a href="#8d70b67c-c667-4fe3-a936-cdd0fc2a1f36">...</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#361cd655-ad54-4cd5-aeb7-a3da9553c1e9">...</a>
```

If I use Javascript

```
var link = newId();
//newId is part of the plugin, but is based on the previous href
element.href = "#" + link;
```

the html changes into

```
<a href="#localhost:1234/#361cd655-ad54-4cd5-aeb7-a3da9553c1e9">...</a>
```

(which is the full address of the page, with the anchor)

and it does not work anymore. However hardcoding it like this would work:

```
element.href = "#361cd655-ad54-4cd5-aeb7-a3da9553c1e9";
```

I've tried quite a few things but I always get similar results.

Comment: What does `newId()` return?

Comment: What is the javascript you use for the click function?

Comment: @SLaks newId() returns a string like 361cd655-ad54-4cd5-aeb7-a3da9553c1e9

Comment: @ltjfansite As far as I'm concerned this is done by the jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can figure out that newId() most likely involves the previous href attribute because if you were to have an anchor element:

```
<a href='page'></a>
```

Even though it is a relative URL, the code

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href
```

would return the full URL (eg. https://serveradmin.xyz/page)

A possible solution is instead of getting the current href, when changing it, also have a variable set to the new value. For example:

```
var linkHref = 1;
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href = linkHref;
//when you next want to change it, don't get the current href, instead, use the link variable
linkHref++;
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href = linkHref;
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
function getRelativeHref(href) {
return href.replace(window.location.href + "#", "");
}
```

If the href parameter was https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51951100/edit#test then it would return #test.

Comment: That seems to be my problem. But isn't there a way reusing the current href? Using a string replacement or similar

Comment: Ah, you could get the url of the current page using window.location.href and replace that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Now it's working. I used a split('#') operation on the href...Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, in my edit, I used replace, but it split would work aswell.

Comment: The replace is a bit easier though. I'll use that, too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problems in your `newId` function. You need something like that:

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", () =>
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('a'),
    a => a.href = "#" + newId())
)

function newId () {
  return Math.random().toString(36); // simple random string.
};
```

```html
<a href="361cd655-ad54-4cd5-aeb7-a3da9553c1e9">...</a>
<button id="btn">Change!</button>
```